# setting div at the bottom of parental div without fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Problem:

On hover div `.galleryIndex` will be "filled" with div `.galleryHover`. `.galleryIndex` has width in percentage and doesn't have fixed height. I want to put div `.white_line_gallery_hover` at the bottom of div `.galleryHover`.

### HTML:

```
 <div class="galleryIndex">
     <img src="images/galleryIndex1.png" class="imageResponsive" />
     <div class="galleryHover">
         <img src="images/kotacGalerija.png" class="imageResponsive" />
         <div class="white_line_gallery_hover">
            Some text
         </div>      
     </div>
 </div>
```

### CSS:

```
.galleryIndex
    {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }

.galleryHover
    {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    background-color: rgba(24, 2, 51, 0.8);
    }

.imageResponsive
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

.white_line_gallery_hover
    {
    width: 90%;
    height: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;

    padding-left: 10%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    }
```

Comment: What goes wrong with what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving ".white_line_gallery_hover" "position: absolute; bottom: 0" and removing the "height: 10%". This will cause "white_line_gallery_hover" to overlay the bottom portion of the image in "galleryIndex".

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ff22qayv/

```css
.galleryIndex
    {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    }

.galleryHover
    {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;

    background-color: rgba(24, 2, 51, 0.8);
    }

.imageResponsive
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

.white_line_gallery_hover
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;

    overflow: hidden;

    padding-left: 10%;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="galleryIndex">
     <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/300/300" class="imageResponsive" />
     <div class="galleryHover">
         <img src="images/kotacGalerija.png" class="imageResponsive" />
         <div class="white_line_gallery_hover">
            Some text
         </div>      
     </div>
 </div>
```

If this is not what you want, you might consider updating your question with a visual representation of the desired result.